# Spotify Auth Flow

Tags: react-native, authentication, oauth, spotify, spotify-app

I am using this library

```
https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth/blob/main/docs/config-examples/spotify.md
```

This library opens the Spotify terms and conditions page in iOS , redirects back to the page, but no callback is called, neither success nor failure. What could there be a reason for this?